# Avoid Naming User Stored Procedures SP% or SP_%

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, query-optimization

Does a user stored procedure with the prefix of SP (not SP_) have poorer performance by looking in the Master DB (similar to user SP named SP_) or does it look in the DB where the stored procedure exists because it lack an underscore?

Comment: Suggestion.  I use "dbo.uspEmployeeGetSingle".  "usp" prefix.  then entity, the action.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [reserved prefix](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25348/still-wrong-to-start-the-name-of-a-user-stored-procedure-with-sp/25367#25367) that exhibits this behaviour is `sp_`. Not `sp`.

A stored procedure called `spAddUser` will be resolved in the normal way without looking for a matching object in `master`.

The relevant [quote in books online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) is

> Avoid the use of the `sp_` prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is
>   used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix
>   can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure
>   with the same name.

But I would avoid these prefixes anyway. If all the stored procedures are prefixed `sp` it quickly gets annoying IMO.

Comment: When all SPs are prefixed by sp, what's the point? this applies to everything else, hungarian notation rarely makes sense

Comment: @BlackTigerX - I agree with you. It is normally pretty obvious from context that an object is a stored procedure (whilst you can also `EXEC` scalar UDFs hardly anyone does). Less annoying than the `tbl` prefix though. After refactoring databases using that you can easily end up with  backward compatibility views replacing tables which still have the `tbl` prefix that is supposed to denote a table!)

Comment: @MartinSmith Does SP_ (upper-case) have the same effect as the lower-case sp_ prefix?

Comment: @user797717 If the instance is case insensitive it does (as it still needs to resolve references with SP_ to the same system objects) but on case sensitive collations it doesn't.