# use % wildcard with ' in ' operator in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a stored procedure and im passing a list of comma separated values as the @At1

```
Create spGetProducts @At1 VARCHAR(200)
begin
select * from tblProducts where Category1 IN (SELECT * FROM CSVToTable(@At2))
end
```

the function CSVToTable basically takes the comma separated values and puts them in a table.

problem is i would like to use a LIKE wildcard with the IN operator however that does not work.

So if i have a in row Category1 a test and the CSVTOTABLE would return a value of 'es', then it would select the row just like if i had %es%.
Basically i just want to have percentage signs in the comma separated values while using the in operator.

im using sql server 2012

EDIT

my CSVTABLE return one column table with each row having a comma separated value.

Comment: Does your function return a single row or multiples?

Comment: Don't use `*` in the IN clause, only exist clause can use that. You need to select a single value

Comment: @DarrenKopp his function obviously returns one column table

Comment: An advice avoid suing `sp` prefix for your stored Procedure names. read here for more information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @M.Ali - [There is no underscore there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530211/avoid-naming-user-stored-procedures-sp-or-sp/20530262#20530262)

Comment: @MartinSmith opss I thought it was true for both `sp_` and `sp`. but it would be nice to avoid it all together. I personally use `usp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace IN with a JOIN ON

```
  select distinct t.* from tblProducts t 
     inner join CSVToTable(@At2) f  
        on t.category1 like f.field1
```

Comment: This might duplicate rows in case of duplicate matches.

Comment: @usr The just add `distinct`

Comment: And what do you do when you don't want distinct results? This is a hack plastered over an underlying deficiency. This is also a potential perf problem.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite the `IN` to `EXISTS` which is more general:

```
select *
from tblProducts p
where exists (
 select *
 from CSVToTable(@At2)
 where Category1 LIKE (SomeExpressionInvolvingTheResultFromCSV)
)
```

You might want to pull the results from `CSVToTable` into a table variable or temp table first for caching reasons.