# SQLDataSource = "Procedure or function [Name] has too many arguments specified."

Tags: c#, sql-server, devexpress, sqldatasource, treelist

I am not sure if its `asp:SqlDataSource` control or it's the `ASPxTreeList` from DevExpress I am using but I am getting a weird error when trying to fire a Stored Procedure using the `Insert()` method.

When adding a node I try to insert the node into the database

```
   protected void TagList_NodeInserting(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataInsertingEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataTagging.InsertCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataTagging.InsertParameters.Add("ParentID", e.NewValues["ParentTag_ID"].ToString());
        SqlDataTagging.InsertParameters.Add("TagName", e.NewValues["TagName_VC"].ToString());
        SqlDataTagging.InsertParameters.Add("UserID", "1");

        SqlDataTagging.InsertCommand = "sp_InsertTag";

        SqlDataTagging.Insert();
    }
```

However when I fire the above code, I get this error

> Procedure or function sp_InsertTag has too many arguments specified.

My SP header

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertTag] (@ParentID INT, @TagName VARCHAR(100), @UserID int)
```

But as you can see, there are 3 parameters in the SP and 3 in the C# code.

Weirdly, if I actually run the SQL via text e.g.

```
SqlDataTagging.InsertCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.Text;
```

and write the SQL in C#, it will work...

Anyone have any ideas or any alternatives so I can use Stored Procedures?

Thanks

Comment: beware of the "sp_" prefix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530211/avoid-naming-user-stored-procedures-sp-or-sp

Comment: Thanks for the warning, still does the same error when I changed the name but something to think about in the future.

Comment: Is `TagList_NodeInserting` being called a 2nd time when this happens? If so is it the same Parameters Collection object? If so are you Clearing the collection before the call? Even if you are clearing the collection, instantiate a new one.

Comment: No, the stored procedure actually fires but the AspxTreelist comes back saying "Procedure or function sp_InsertTag has too many arguments specified." all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have `SqlDataSource` with ID `SqlDataTagging` to populate tree nodes, the error occurs if [TagList_NodeInserting](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxTreeListASPxTreeList_NodeInsertingtopic) method fires more than once, hence at certain point `InsertParameters` collection populates with more than 3 parameters specified in stored procedure.

To mitigate this behavior, I suggest you clearing `InsertParameters` collection before adding parameters like below:

```
...
SqlDataTagging.InsertCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataTagging.InsertParameters.Clear(); // add this line to clear InsertParameters collection before adding parameters
SqlDataTagging.InsertParameters.Add("ParentID", e.NewValues["ParentTag_ID"].ToString());
SqlDataTagging.InsertParameters.Add("TagName", e.NewValues["TagName_VC"].ToString());
SqlDataTagging.InsertParameters.Add("UserID", "1");
...
```

Related issue:

[ASPxTreeList - The 'Procedure or function [name] has too many arguments specified' exception is raised when a node is deleted](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q387255) (similar approach)