# SQL Server - filter query by variable number of parameters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

The scenario:

1. I have a stored procedure (`spFetch`) that I want to return a list
   of results from a table.
2. The stored procedure (`spFetch`) defines a number of
   parameters that may or may not be passed in by the caller.  If parameter values are not passed
   in by the caller they default to null.
3. If any of these parameters
   are not null, they should be used in the where clause of the select
   statement in (`spFetch`) to return filtered results.
4. I have a front end app that will act the caller, but it is not set
   in stone as to how the parameters should be passed (comma seperated
   list, explicit reference, etc)

The idea here is that, on the back end I can limit the possible query parameters, while still allowing a wide range of parameters.

How do i write `spFetch` so that it meets all the requirements of the above scenario?

There has to be a best practice out there for this scenerio, its crazy to think other devs arn't doing this already right?

Comment: http://sqlsentry.tv/the-kitchen-sink-procedure/

Comment: Most aren't doing it with a comma separated list cause you'll have to then split that list. Look into table value parameters to go along with the kitchen sink link from @LukaszSzozda

Comment: just a side note, you normally don't want to name stored procedures starting with sp as it _could_ conflict with a system one which starts with sp_  so just name yours usp_  or something

Comment: @sniperd - could conflict? How?

Comment: Kitchen sink is definitely the answer, awesome solution!  @Lukasz Szozda,  want to officially add it as an answer so I can mark right?

Comment: @JamieMarshall there are a bunch of built in stored procedures, such as sp_addarticle so you wouldn't want to make a user created stored procedure with the same name.  So if you _always_ just name your stored procedures with usp_ or some other prefix you won't have a conflict.

Comment: @sniperd so sp is fine then, as opposed to sp_ yes?

Comment: @JamieMarshall I think you'd be OK with sp, I just like having it be very different in part so if I have to do mass updates or sorting it's easy.  But yes it looks like sp is OK but perhaps not preferable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530211/avoid-naming-user-stored-procedures-sp-or-sp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_Search] ( @Name sysname = NULL, @Objectid INT  = NULL, @schemaId INT  = NULL )
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        [name]
       ,[object_id]
       ,[principal_id]
       ,[schema_id]
       ,[parent_object_id]
       ,[type]
       ,[type_desc]
       ,[create_date]
       ,[modify_date]
       ,[is_ms_shipped]
       ,[is_published]
       ,[is_schema_published]
    FROM
        [sys].[objects]
    WHERE 1                                = 1
          AND [name]                         = ISNULL(@Name, [name])
          AND ISNULL(@Objectid, [object_id]) = [object_id]
          AND ISNULL(@schemaId, [schema_id]) = [schema_id];
END;

EXEC p_search @Name = 'sysallocunits'
```

Comment: Thanks @amy-b for the formatting ; still trying to figure out the formatting options