# Having trouble with: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open. - SQL Server & C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm currently working on the login form of a school management system. The thing is that when I try to log in, I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open

It says that the error is on the 30th line of code but I can't seem to find a way to solve it.

Here's the code of the method in which the error occurs:

```
public void LoginTeacher()
{
        try
        {
            command = new SqlCommand("TeacherLogin", connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            connection.Open(); // This is the 30th line. 

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Txt_User.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Txt_Pass.Text);

            SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (dataReader.Read())
            { 
                    TeacherDash teacherDash = new TeacherDash();
                    this.Hide();
                    teacherDash.lblusertype.Text = dataReader[1] + " " + dataReader[2].ToString();
                    teacherDash.ShowDialog();
                    this.Close();
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
}
```

Immediately after that error is shown there is another one that says:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call CheckDataIsReady when reader is closed

and points to line 71 which is the following:

```
public void Login()
{
        try
        {
            command = new SqlCommand("SP_USER_LOGIN", connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            connection.Open();

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", Txt_User.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", Txt_Pass.Text);

            SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (dataReader.Read())
            {
                LoginTeacher();

                if (dataReader[10].Equals("Admin"))
                {
                    AdminDash adminDash = new AdminDash();
                    this.Hide();
                    adminDash.lblusertype.Text = dataReader[1] + " " + dataReader[2].ToString();
                    adminDash.ShowDialog();

                    this.Close();
                }
```

There's more code after that but I don't find it relevant since it's the same thing but with the different type of users.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't be sharing the `connection` like that, create it in the method that uses it and put it inside a `using` block

Comment: Please paste the _exact_ error, don't paraphrase it or give us excerpts. But yeah, JSteward is right, you shouldn't share the connection object round like that. Don't worry too much about appearing to open and close connections a lot - ADO.NET uses [connection pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) so in reality you won't be opening as many physical connections to the DB as your code appears to make.

Comment: ADO.NET handles connection pooling for you under the covers. It is best practice to create a new connection for every sql statement/query you want to execute. Do this by wrapping the connection instances in `using` blocks to ensure they are released / closed. This is your main issue as your code appears to be trying to share a single connection which was previously closed.

Comment: On an unrelated note do not prefix your store procedures names with `sp_`. This is a reserved naming convention for internal objects in sql server. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/20530262/1260204

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing your TeacherLogin() method to something like the following:

```
public void TeacherLogin()
{
    try
    {
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
        {
            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("TeacherLogin"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Txt_User.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Txt_Pass.Text);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while(dr.Read())
                    {
                        TeacherDash teacherDash = new TeacherDash();
                        this.Hide();
                        teacherDash.lblusertype.Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", dr[1], dr[2]);
                        teacherDash.ShowDialog();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

There's no need to use finally{} to close the connection as its all wrapped in a using() block, it will close and dispose on its own when the code leaves the block. I'd always recommend using SQL connections and commands in this way as not doing so can cause issues by leaving connections open.

Comment: I see syntax errors as well as the swallowing of good exception information that could have been used to help debug runtime errors..

Comment: @Igor That will teach me to write this stuff out in notepad instead of a proper tool! I've corrected a few things in the example now. The exception information can be captured in the catch and handled by the poster's own code or ignored entirely as they see fit, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Database object need to be closed and disposed. Keeping them local to the method where they are used lets you make sure this happens. using blocks take care of this for you.

I used a `DataTable` instead of testing with the reader because the connection must remain open as long as the reader is in use. Opening and closing the connection in the briefest possible time is important.

Please don't use `.AddWithValue`. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html
 Of course you will have to check your database for the real datatypes and field size to have the correct .Add method.

```
    public void LoginTeacher()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("TeacherLogin", cn))
        { 
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@username",SqlDbType.VarChar,100 ).Value = Txt_User.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@password",SqlDbType.VarChar, 100 ).Value =Txt_Pass.Text;
            cn.Open();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        } //Your connection and command are both disposed
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            TeacherDash teacherDash = new TeacherDash();
            teacherDash.lblusertype.Text = $"{dt.Rows[0][1]} {dt.Rows[0][2]}";
            teacherDash.ShowDialog();
            Close();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, login failed");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

make it async method.It may fix.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).