# Stored procedures - jumbled mess

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have to create 2 stored procedures.

```
sp_InsertNewMenuItem 

sp_InsertIngredient
```

I went ahead and got rid of the sp in the names of the procedures.

InsertNewMenuItem checks if the MenuTitle, MenuGroupText, or MenuItemTitle exists. If it doesn't it adds +1 to the ID and inserts the new menu item into the menu.

`InsertIngredient` which creates and inserts an ingredient into the menu item from the first procedure.

Here are the tables I used:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Menu](
[ID] INT PRIMARY KEY identity(1,1),
[MenuTitle] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[MenuDescriptionText] [nvarchar](50) NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MenuGroups](
[ID] INT PRIMARY KEY identity(1,1),
[MenuID] INT NOT NULL,
[MenuGroupText] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[MenuGroupDescriptionText] [nvarchar](50) NULL, 
FOREIGN KEY (MenuID) REFERENCES Menu(ID))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MenuItems](
[ID] INT PRIMARY KEY identity(1,1),
[MenuGroupsID] INT NOT NULL,
[MenuItemTitle] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[MenuItemDescriptionText] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (MenuGroupsID) REFERENCES MenuGroups(ID))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ingredients](
[ID] INT PRIMARY KEY identity(1,1),
[IngredientTitleText] [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
[IngredientDescriptionText] [NVARCHAR](200) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IngredientsInItems](
[ID] INT PRIMARY KEY identity(1,1),
[IngredientsID] INT NOT NULL,
[MenuItemID] INT NOT NULL, 
[DescriptionText] [NVARCHAR](200), 
FOREIGN KEY (IngredientsID) REFERENCES Ingredients(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (MenuItemID) REFERENCES MenuItems(ID))
```

Here is the first procedure and executing it:

```
`CREATE PROCEDURE InsertNewMenuItem
    @MenuTitle NVARCHAR(50),
    @MenuGroupText NVARCHAR(50),
    @MenuItemTitle NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @MenuID INT;

    -- Check for existing Menu and create if needed
    SELECT @MenuID = ID FROM dbo.Menu WHERE MenuTitle = @MenuTitle;
    IF @MenuID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.Menu (MenuTitle, MenuDescriptionText)
        VALUES (@MenuTitle, NULL);
        SELECT @MenuID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();  -- Get newly generated MenuID
    END

    DECLARE @MenuGroupID INT;

    -- Check for existing MenuGroup and create if needed
    SELECT @MenuGroupID = ID FROM dbo.MenuGroups WHERE MenuID = @MenuID AND MenuGroupText = @MenuGroupText;
    IF @MenuGroupID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.MenuGroups (MenuID, MenuGroupText, MenuGroupDescriptionText)
        VALUES (@MenuID, @MenuGroupText, NULL);
        SELECT @MenuGroupID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();  -- Get newly generated MenuGroupID
    END

    -- Create the MenuItem
    INSERT INTO dbo.MenuItems (MenuGroupsID, MenuItemTitle, MenuItemDescriptionText)
    VALUES (@MenuGroupID, @MenuItemTitle, NULL);
END
`

`EXEC InsertNewMenuItem 'Main Menu', 'Tacos', 'Basic Taco';`

`EXEC InsertNewMenuItem 'Main Menu', 'Tacos', 'Chicken Cheese Taco';`
```

and here are the results:

```
`select * from Menu, MenuGroups, MenuItems`

`Main Menu  NULL    1   1   Tacos   NULL    1   1   Basic Taco  NULL


Main Menu   NULL    1   1   Tacos   NULL    2   1   Chicken Cheese Taco NULL`
```

The problem happens when I try to execute the second procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertIngredient
    @IngredientTitleText NVARCHAR(50),
    @MenuItemID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @IngredientID INT;

    -- Check if the ingredient already exists and get its ID
    SELECT @IngredientID = ID FROM dbo.Ingredients WHERE IngredientTitleText = @IngredientTitleText;
    IF @IngredientID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.Ingredients (IngredientTitleText)
        VALUES (@IngredientTitleText);
        SELECT @IngredientID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();  -- Get newly generated IngredientID
    END

    -- Insert the ingredient into the IngredientsInItems table
    INSERT INTO dbo.IngredientsInItems (IngredientsID, MenuItemID)
    VALUES (@IngredientID, @MenuItemID);
END 

`DECLARE @MenuItemID INT = 2; 

EXEC InsertIngredient 'Chicken', @MenuItemID;`
```

It puts the ingredients into both lines.

```
`Main Menu  NULL    1   1   Tacos   NULL    1   1   Basic Taco  NULL    1   Chicken NULL

Main Menu   NULL    1   1   Tacos   NULL    2   1   Chicken Cheese Taco NULL    1   Chicken NULL`
```

How do I fix this? Nothing seems to help.

Comment: Your query is unreadable. I have format it for you.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data, only paste text. Which table is that data of? It doesn't seem to match any of your tables, is it just some joined query? And what is contained now in the other tables?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530211/avoid-naming-user-stored-procedures-sp-or-sp

Comment: When you have that many if statements in a proc you're going wrong. SQL is a set based language not a procedural language. Conditions can go in where clauses, check for whether an insert was made with `@@rowcount`.

Comment: And please don't use images. The editor supports markdown tables which can be easily viewed on any device. Finally you to provide a [mre] of what you are trying to accomplish i.e. sample data and desired results - otherwise we have no idea what those procs are attempting to do.

Comment: **Side note**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure is uncorrect and will delever some false positive data...

Developers always forget two fundamental things when developing database procedures:

**concurrency**: what will happen if two different users launch the same procedure at the same time

**the set based processing**: the databases do not operate according to an iterative code, but as a set transformation

As an example, this code :

```
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM [dbo].[ingredients]
                   WHERE [ingredienttitletext] = @IngredientTitleText)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[ingredients] ([ingredienttitletext])
        VALUES (@IngredientTitleText)
```

Executed in concurrencey will INSERTs two rows...

```
Time 0 | User A                         | User B
       | SELECT 1                       | SELECT 1 
       | FROM ingredients               | FROM ingredients 
       | WHERE ...                      | WHERE ... 

Time 1 | INSERT INTO ingredients        | < wait because INSERT locks>
       | VALUES (@IngredientTitleText)  | ...

Time 2 |                                | INSERT INTO ingredients
       |                                | VALUES (@IngredientTitleText)
```

Will give a duplicate entry. Because reader can be more than one to read at the same time....

The only way to do not have duplicate is to use UNIQUE constraints. There is no other way !